# But these textbooks were bought by them. / But these textbooks they bought

Tags: phrase-choice

Which version would be idiomatic? I have the second version in my English study book and was surprised by their construction. Is it idiomatic to speak like that? "But these textbooks they bought."?

> All of the students take the books from the library. But **these textbooks were bought by them**.
>
> All of the students take the books from the library. But **these textbooks they bought**.

P.S. If it's possible to speak about that in this post, could you answer about "the books". If I speak about all the books in that library, I must use "the books" or "books"? I think "the books" is better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both possible.

The first is a passive form, with the subject taking the semantic role of the object.

The second is active, but the object has been fronted in "yoda-speak".

While these are possible grammar, most people would use the active "But they bought these textbooks." The fronting of "These textbooks" is a rhetorical device to focus on the textbooks.

Comment: If I understand right, the speaking Object-Subject-Verb existed much earlier than Star Wars. It can be used during some presentation, but speaking like that can be considered as mistaken on a formal examination. Right?

Comment: Yes, it existed before star wars.  It has always been a rhetorical option. I don't know about "formal examination", it depends what is being examined.  It is an entirely valid construction, with a specific rhetorical purpose.  If you use it incorrectly... that is incorrect.